# Is it possible to add css class to the page's body tag with rules when certain conditions are met?

Tags: rules

I seem to have read that there is a way of making Rules add a css class to the body tag, but I can't find out how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you need Rules for that ? 
You can do it in theme level (template.php, individual page template, etc). 

I'm not aware of such action or a combination of rules to do that either.

Comment: To do it conditionally, so that the page's body get a  gets a class after an event has occured. Thanks for your comment, I'll edit the title to make it clearer

Comment: A Rules event is a one-off temporary firing of an event, if you're adding a body class triggered by that, it will only be added once, after that event is triggered. Keep in mind you can add body classes in hook_preprocess_html in template.php with conditional logic.

Comment: @DavidThomas: That's exactly the kind of behaviour I expect. I want to graphics to change after  a product has been added, and the changed graphics should be there until the order is completed or all products have been removed (that'd require another rule, I guess). The suggestion below seems promising

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - the [Context module](http://drupal.org/project/context) allows you to add CSS classes to the body (Theme HTML condition) based on whatever events you specify. You would then combine this with the [Context Rules](http://drupal.org/project/context_rules) module which extends Context to allow for context events from Rules.

Comment: Great, will give that solution a try.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module to automatically create semantic paths  your content pages based on the menu path you can use the page's path to create the classes you are looking for:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias();
  $aliases = explode('/', $path);

  foreach($aliases as $alias) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = drupal_clean_css_identifier($alias);
  } 
}
```

Comment: The OP is expressly talking about the Rule module. Also, it is preferable to tailor the answer to the question being asked; generally answering to a question would probably add a useless answer.