# Commerce - adding a class to the body element when there is an item in the cart

Tags: commerce

Is there a way to add a class to the body element if there are one or more items in a shopping cart?

I'm using Drupal 7.38 and Commerce 7.1. I have to admit that I haven't tried anything to achieve my goal, apart from searching the interwebs - I have no idea how to add a class when a certain event happens.

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate): http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70741/is-it-possible-to-add-css-class-to-the-pages-body-tag-with-rules-when-certain-c. Please let me know if that solves your problem

Comment: @Clive Thanks for the link. I guess it answers my question, albeit in a very minimal way ("it's possible with rules and these modules"). It didn't get me very far ;(.

Comment: Worth a shot :) Might be a good idea to edit this question and add "I understand it's possible with the context module, but how?" or similar, it may encourage a more thorough answer