# Custom Image Background in Block

Tags: 7

I tried Dynamic background module but it seems it's not what I am looking for. Is there such a module that will allow me to change the background for a certain pages or group of pages that works the same like block?

Like in Block, I can select which pages this block will be shown.

Example:

```
    Show background on specific pages
         All pages except those listed
         Only the listed pages
```

I believe there's a module that can do this, I would be very glad if somebody can point me to the URL of the module.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this answer may help https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236069/why-the-content-of-a-block-created-in-an-external-module-does-not-appear/236078#236078

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via a class that you selectively add to the pages, then using CSS add a background. Two modules stand out:

[Node Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_class)

> Node Class is a simple module that allows users to add custom CSS
>   classes to any node through the node/add interface.

[Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context)

> Context allows you to manage contextual conditions and reactions for
>   different portions of your site. You can think of each context as
>   representing a "section" of your site. For each context, you can
>   choose the conditions that trigger this context to be active and
>   choose different aspects of Drupal that should react to this active
>   context.

See also:

[Is it possible to add css class to the page's body tag with rules when certain conditions are met?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70741/is-it-possible-to-add-css-class-to-the-pages-body-tag-with-rules-when-certain-c)

and

[Context Block Classes](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_block_class)

Answer (score 0):

Check out these module :

[Jq maphilight](https://www.drupal.org/project/jq_maphilight)

> 1. provides simple interactive graphics via HTML image maps (no flash   required).
> 2. easy to use: either select the 'highlight all image maps' default > setting or simply add class="jq_maphilight" to the  tag of any specific image map you wish to highlight.
> 3. no jquery or javascript knowledge required: plugin configuration is handled via an admin/settings screen rather than having to enter jquery code.
> 4. fully configurable: options for fill, fill color, fill opacity, outline, outline color, outline opacity, outline thickness, as well as a fade effect.
> 5. per image map settings: add image map specific options with an additional class.

[qTip](https://www.drupal.org/project/qtip/)

> qTips are stylish tooltips that can be configured and styled (more to
>   come in later releases) to fit nearly any website's design.

[Background Images Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image_formatter)

> 1. You want to display a image on the back of a div when viewing a particular node.
> 2. You want to display a random image on the back of a div on the frontpage only. This can be done using Views. Create a block, select the "Background Image" formatter for your image field, save, place the block, boom, you're done.

or you can do it by using node id or create hierarchy of css