# Why the content of a block created in an external module does not appear?

Tags: blocks

I am creating a module for wich i need to create a block with php code. I`m making it as follow:

```
function my_modulo_block_info() {
   $blocks = array();
   $blocks['start'] = array(
      'title' => 'Start',
      'info' => t('The start block'),
      'status' => TRUE,
      'region' => 'content',
   );
   return $blocks;
}

function my_modulo_block_view($delta='') {
   $block = array();
   switch($delta) {
      case 'start' :
         $block['content'] = '<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>';
         break;
   }
   return $block;
}
```

But i see only the block name on the page, it dont print Hello world. Any body know why?

Comment: Do you actually want `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` or do you want 'Hello World' to display?  If you want the php, I am wondering if it is in your html but you don't see it in the browser because of the `<>`  maybe try using `&lt;` and `&gt;`  or if you do just want 'Hello World' then change the line to `$block['content'] = 'Hello world';`

Comment: I really need the php code, "Hello world" is only an example for undeerstand. Wath are &lt and &gt ?

Comment: They are character codes [link](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).  `&lt;` = `<` and `&gt;` = `>`  You might also use the php function highlight_string() [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php)

Comment: That is not the problem, it seems that the block does not recognize php code. I do not know how to define the block that recognizes php code, just like full html and plain text format on configure block pages.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "recognizes php code."  What to you actually want to see in the browser?  The `$block['content']` variable is for the HTML content you want to display.

Comment: Let's see how I explain myself better
When a block is created through the drupal interface, the name, description, body and text format are written. This way you can choose the format to "php code" and write php code in the body of the block. I need to do the same but using the hooks that provides drupal to work with blocks. Do you understand me now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58625/discussion-between-dyn-and-r-leurquin).

Comment: Ignoring the fact that you should never ever use the php filter for a second - its intended use is when you _can't_ do it properly in PHP. Since your block is coded, it makes no sense at all to make its content php. PHP won't randomly execute a string, you would theoretically need to run that code through `check_markup` with the php format to make that happen. But definitely don't do that, just execute the PHP

Answer (score 2):

call a php function to built block-content, in hook_view code should be:

```
//construct your output as a function    
$block['content'] = myfunctionname(); // this function is called 3 lines below
....
return $block;
//then call your output content function
function myfunctionname() {
$output = 'whatever you want(arrays, functions, html, more php, ....)'
 };
 return $output;
```

that will return $output as your content.

Comment: It's preferable to return a render array as the content, but this is the right idea