# how to change h2 tag for div in block_view

Tags: blocks, hooks

I've created a block like this

```
function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {
    if($delta == 'myblock') {
        $block['subject'] = 'mytitle';
        $block['content'] = myfunction();
    }
    return $block;
}
```

but the output is like this:

```
<h2 class="block-title">mytitle</h2>
```

I need change `h2` to `div`

```
<div class="block-title">mytitle</div>
```

I've tried with `_preprocess_block` hook but i cant change that tag

could you please help me?

Comment: this may help https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236069/why-the-content-of-a-block-created-in-an-external-module-does-not-appear/236078#236078

Comment: Override the default block template. Try: "How to theme a custom block" https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/39270/28700

Comment: hi, thanks @pinueve but that add a div tag inside h2, <h2>title<div></div></h2>

Comment: You could use a theme hook with a template thus have complete control of your html output. Take a look here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39023/how-to-theme-a-custom-block

Comment: just built $content in yourfuction($args);

Comment: @seroton thanks but that add a div tag inside h2, <h2>title<div></div></h2>

Answer (score 0):

try with the following:

1. Implement `hook_theme_registry_alter` to take the templates from your module.

```
/**
 *  Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  // Defined path to the current module.
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . "/templates";
  // Find all .tpl.php files in this module's folder recursively.
  $template_file_objects = drupal_find_theme_templates($theme_registry, '.tpl.php', $module_path);
  // Iterate through all found template file objects.
  //test if this page isn't in BO page
  if (!path_is_admin(current_path())) {
    foreach ($template_file_objects as $key => $template_file_object) {
      // If the template has not already been overridden by a theme.
      if (!isset($theme_registry[$key]['theme path']) || !preg_match('#/themes/#', $theme_registry[$key]['theme path'])) {
        // Alter the theme path and template elements.
        $theme_registry[$key]['theme path'] = $module_path;
        $theme_registry[$key] = array_merge($theme_registry[$key], $template_file_object);
        $theme_registry[$key]['type'] = 'module';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Copy `modules/block/block.tpl.php` and past it in `templates` folder of your module.
3. Rename it from `block.tpl.php` to `block--mymodule--myblock.tpl.php` to change only for your block.
4. Change the line from `<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $block->subject ?></h2>` to `<div<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $block->subject ?></div>`
5. Clear cache.